# Detect wifi with quotas

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, hotspot, quota

I saw that at least Ubuntu has a way to detect wifis with quota, as when I was connected to my phone's 4G hotspot I got a message that I could not search for apps in the ubuntu software center for this reason.

How can I access such a state in, let's say, a bash script? The ultimate goal is to prevent backup through rsync when I'm connected to 4G.

Comment: Might be easier to determine what wireless link you are using. I never automate sync operations to prevent occurrence at an inappropriate time.

Comment: You mean like finding the SSID of my phone? It looks like there exists a cleaner way...

Comment: You could do that and then you know what device you are using.